# From a Waveform to a .wav file

Tags: audio, python, audio-processing

I would like to make an autoencoder for music generation using PyTorch.
In input, I would like to have a Waveform (from a .wav file) and I want the output to be a Waveform.
My problem is that I don't know how to get a .wav file from a waveform that is the output...
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a soundfile package.  There's also `scipy.io.wavfile`

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB you can create a .wav file `waveFileName.wav` from a waveform `y` with sampling frequency `Fs` using MATLAB's [audiowrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html) as follows:

```
filename = 'waveFileName.wav';
audiowrite(filename,y,Fs);
```

You can also read and output a waveform `y` and its sampling frequency `Fs` from the .wav file `waveFileName.wav` using MATLAB's [audioread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) as follows.

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('waveFileName.wav');
```

I am sure there must be corresponding functions in Python.